# Как правильно расширить функциональность класса WebSocket

Tags: node.js, websocket, typescript

Есть необходимость расширить функциональность каждого экземпляра `WebSocket` которого я получаю при установке соединения.

Мне нужно там хранить идентификатор клиента который сервер получает от него в первом сообщении.

**Пробую так**

```
wss.on('connection', (ws : WebSocket) => {  
  ws.on('message', (message : string) => {
    const incomMessage = JSON.parse(message);
    if(incomMessage.type === 'hello') {
      ws.token = incomMessage.token; //здесь ошибка
    }
  });
});
```

Ругается на то что у `WebSocket` нет поля `token`.

Ладно подумал я и решил расширить класс `WebSocket`.

```
class MySocket extends WebSocket {
  token : string;
}

wss.on('connection', (ws : MySocket) => {  
  // тело
});
```

Так не ругается но кажется мне что это костыль, а не решение. Я ведь все равно получаю в `ws` инстанс `WebSocket` а не `MySocket`. Хотелось бы поле `token` сделать приватным и добавить геттер и сеттер.

**Пробовал вот так**

```
class MySocket extends WebSocket {
  privat token : string;

  setToken(token : string) {
    this.token = token;
  }
  getToken() {
    return this.token;
  }
}

wss.on('connection', (ws : MySocket) => {  
  // тело
});
```

Но при обращению к методам `ws.getToken()` и `ws.setToken('token')` я получаю ошибку, что не удивительно так как мой `ws` все таки `WebSocket` а не `MySocket`.

Вопрос - Как правильно в `WebSocket` добавить приватное поле с геттером и сеттером?

Answer (score 0):

Возникает вопрос, действительно ли в данном случае требуется наследование? К примеру, данную задачу можно решить через оборачивание экземпляра `WebSocket`:

```
class Connection {
  private socket: WebSocket;
  private token: string;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = this.createSocket();
  }

  getToken() { return this.token; }

  private createSocket() {
    const wss = /* ... */;
    wss.on('connection', (ws: WebSocket) => {  
      ws.on('message', message => this.onMessage(message));
    });
    return wss;
  }

  private onMessage(message: string) {
    const incomMessage = JSON.parse(message);
    if (incomMessage.type === 'hello') {
      this.token = incomMessage.token;
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: мне нужно на каждое соединение сохранять свой токен. В вашем случае токен перезаписывается при каждом соединении.

Comment: @torokhkun В данном примере так и происходит: каждое соединение представляется как отдельный экземпляр `Connection`, со своим сокетом.